# Passing string arrays between Managed C++ and VBA

Tags: c++, vba

What's the proper way to pass an array of strings from managed C++ to VBA? I want to pass a string array from Managed C++ out to VBA. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an `array<String^>^`, the COM interop built into the CLR turns it into a COM Automation compatible array, a SAFEARRAY of BSTR.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at some form of RPC, or something that acts as a middle man. I've seen instances of Facebook Thrift I believe, but I don't think that would suit your needs due to the overhead, and I am not sure if it supports VBA. Also worth noting is the mangled C++, it would be better to declare them with __cdecl "c" or something of the sort to avoid that problem, and get unmangled names.